# Is there a method to link an external managed database to a dokku application?

Tags: postgresql, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I have been attempting to link a Digital Ocean managed database to an app I am running on one of their droplets, a VPS.

I have attempted creating a service with custom environment variables using the dokku postgres library found [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres) but the DATABASE_URL is still incorrectly set and points to local addresses, not the externally hosted parameters I need set.

Is using --custom-env flag with the parameters gathered from DigitalOcean's control panel a correct way of doing this when creating the service with the following command

```
dokku postgres:create <service> [--create-flags...]
```

?

Is connecting to an external database with dokku even possible?

I am able to create local docker containers of postgres instances and link to those from the app without issue. I only have problems when I try to point to the external managed database service.

At this stage I am assuming this is an architectural issue that I am facing and am reassessing where I deploy my apps. Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Comment: For some reason I cannot edit my original question. I believe I am going about this entirely wrong. I shouldn't be creating a service with dokku that links to the external database somehow, I should be simply pointing my app to interface directly with the managed database by setting the env var DATABASE_URL to one that matches the URI provided by DigitalOcean. I will attempt this and report back once I get a chance (probably a week or so from now).

Answer (score 0):

I know you solved this for yourself, but in case anyone else stumbles on it (neither Dokku or DO makes it clear how to do this), the solution is to set an environment variable in Dokku using the "DATABASE_URL" key.

`dokku config:set <app> DATABASE_URL="<your_DO_db_connection_string>"`